# Attaching an event listener to all URLRequest's

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flexbuilder, flex4.5

We have a flex application that connects to a proxy server which handles authentication. If the authentication has timeout out the proxy server returns a json formatted error string. What I would like to do is inspect every URLRequest response and check if there's an error message and display it in the flex client then redirect back to login screen.

So I'm wondering if its possible to create an event listener to all URLRequests in a global fashion. Without having to search through the project and add some method to each URLRequest. Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're only using one service, there is no way to set a global URLRequest handler.  If I were you, I'd think more about architecting your application properly by using a delegate and always checking the result through a particular service which is used throughout the app.

Comment: Unfortunately and perhaps unsurprisingly its a large inherited outsourced jumble of code. Re-architecting is pretty much out of the question

Comment: @RueTheWhirled You're gonna have to change 'em all anyway ... maybe you _should_ use the opportunity to refactor the code a little, and introduce a delegate?

Answer (score 2):

J_A_X has some good suggestions, but I'd take it a bit farther.  Let me make some assumptions based on the limited information you've provided.

1. The services are scattered all over your application means that they're actually embedded in multiple Views.
2. If your services can all be handled by the same handler, you notionally have one service, copied many times.

Despite what you see in the Adobe examples showing their new Service generation code, it's incredibly bad practice to call services directly from Views, in part because of the very problem you are seeing--you can wind up with lots of copies of the same service code littered all over your application.

Depending on how tightly interwoven your application is (believe me, I've inherited some pretty nasty stuff, so I know this might be easier said than done), you may find that the easiest thing is to remove all of those various services and replace them by having all your Views dispatch a bubbling event that gets caught at the top level.  At the top level, you respond to that event by calling **one** instance of your service, which is again handled in **one** place.

You may or may not choose to wrap that single service in a delegate, but once you have your application archtected in a way where the service is decoupled from your Views, you can make that choice at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to extend the class and add an event listener in the object's constructor? I don't like this approach but it could work.

You would just have to search/replace the whole project.